# What is the equation for this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question is from Goldberg's book and I couldn't figure out the equation for this sequence -

$S_{n}=\{1,3,6,10,15,...\}$

I wanted to know about the equation governing this sequence.

Answer (score 5):

There could of course be many ways this could be interpreted. The most obvious is probably

$$ 1, 3 = 1 + 2, 6 = 1 + 2 + 3, \dots $$

so $$ S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Answer (score 2):

$S_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. In general look for simple polynomials as solutions. In this case, however you can notice that it is the sum of first n terms.